# Gurobi Python: Writing a Constraint with Two Indices

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi

[image: Constraint]

I'm currently working on a linear programming problem using Gurobi in Python, and I'm facing difficulty in writing a constraint where the coefficients involve two indices.
I have saved bij in a matrix:  (x and z are decision variables)

```
    #print(costanti)
   
    b = [[distanza * costante for distanza, costante in zip(riga, costanti)] for riga in distance]
  ...
....
....
..transpose the matrix...
    b = np.array(b)
 
    # Reshape the array to a 2x1 matrix
    b = b.reshape((2, 2))
```

and then to add the constraint:

`model.addConstrs((gp.quicksum(b[i, j] * x[i, j, k] for i in I) <= B * z[j, k] for j in J for k in K), name="constraint3")`

The error I get is: list indices must be integers or slices not tuple.
Do you know how I can solve the problem?

Comment: What is `x`? What is `z`? I'm guessing one of these (or both) is a list of list, so you cannot use `x[i, j, k]` you need to use `x[i][j][k]`.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this problem because your `b` variable is a Numpy array and Gurobi doens't support its using in contraints!

You can solve it in different ways, one is using Gurobi's LinExpr() as follows:

```
for j in J:
    for k in K:
        expr = LinExpr()
        for i in I:
            expr += b[i, j] * x[i, j, k]
        model.addConstr(expr <= B * z[j, k], name=f"constraint3_{j}_{k}")
```

I hope this will solve your problem, but please check if the constraint I created is what you wanted.